# Can't search drive files within Gmail anymore

Tags: gmail, google-drive, gmail-search, google-drive-search

I've noticed my queries using the search bar in Gmail don't return files in my Google Drive anymore. The files used to appear as a suggestion below the bar while I was typing. Is there a way to turn that feature on again?

I found some questions regarding this around 2016, when apparently Google started to demand the activation of a Gmail lab for this to work (Labs are defunct now). I have the impression this feature stopped working for me way after 2016 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google representative [confirmed](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/78346695/gmail-search-doesn-t-find-drive-documents-anymore) this feature was discontinued in late 2020:

> That bar is only an email search bar now. It no longer does web searches, nor finds Contacts, Drive files, nor anything else. -tony_b (Platinum Product Expert)